# How to make udev update battery status more often?

Tags: power-management, indicator, battery, charging

[image: You can see that on the picture it says updated and then 99 seconds]Ubuntu battery icon uses about 1-2 minutes before recognizing charger being plugged in or out. How to make the battery status update more often so that it recognizes the charger immediately.

The problem was not present in Ubuntu 14.10. The problem started with 15.04, and was present in 15.10. I am now on 16.04

I am using a MacBookAir early 2014 model.

You can see that on the picture it says updated and then 99 seconds
And `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0` gives me this when I have unplugged the charger:

```
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               SMP
  model:                bq20z451
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              fr. 01. jan. 2016 kl. 21.29 +0100 (1 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               charging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              19,2888 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         48,1992 Wh
    energy-full-design:  54,34 Wh
    energy-rate:         7,3112 W
    voltage:             7,868 V
    time to full:        4,0 hours
    percentage:          36%
    temperature:         32,8 degrees C
    capacity:            88,6993%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-good-charging-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1451680147  36,000  charging
  History (rate):
    1451680164  7,311   charging
    1451680147  24,183  charging
```

Comment: Sounds like a problem related to your hardware. Tell us which laptop you're using, maybe someone knows how to fix it.

Comment: @TomTasche I have added info now

Comment: I am now on 16.04

Comment: let verify Tom idea, run `udevadm monitor -u` then plug/unplug charger, see if it does respond quickly without delay (Normal 1~2 sec)

Comment: @Sneetsher Of course my bad

Comment: @HåvardPettersen , how much delay did you got?

Comment: @Sneetsher About 1 minute. Gnome Power Manager: BAT0 updated=113sec       AC=335sec

Comment: @Sneetsher If we could get Gnome-power-manger to update AC and BAT0 state all the time, the problem would bes solved. I just do not know how to do that.

Comment: @HåvardPettersen , does the udev messages have this delay too?

Comment: @Sneetsher Not quite sure how to check that, the command I run earlier? No, I think it is jsut gnome-power-manager that does not update often enough

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33724/discussion-between-sneetsher-and-havard-pettersen).

Answer (score 0):

An effective workaround was to add `acpi_osi=` as a kernel parameter

This is done by editing the configuration file for GRUB, for example, run

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line beginning `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` and add the new parameter to those already there, so when you are done, it looks, for example, like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Save the file and exit, then to make the change effective, run

```
sudo update-grub
```